# How can i add a custom input filed (not attribute) using phtml in product edit page in magneto 2.4

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-options, product-edit

I want to add a custom checkbox list filed (not attribute)in product edit page. Therefore I call a phtml file in product admin and set checkbox input filed (which is dynamic).But when i am using observer "controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after" and print $_POST value my custom filed is not showing or coming.

i am shsreing the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="add_product_label_ids">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Label</item>
               <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">9999</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
       <container name="add_product_label_ids" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
           <htmlContent name="html_content_demo">
               <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Custommization\Productlabelcustomization\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Productlabel</argument>
           </htmlContent>
       </container>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

then in Custommization\Productlabelcustomization\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Productlabel

```
<?php
namespace Custommization\Productlabelcustomization\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
class Productlabel extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'Productlabel.phtml';

    protected $_systemStore;

    protected $_scopeConfig;
    
    protected $_labellistFactory;
    
    protected $objectManager;
    
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Custommization\Productlabelcustomization\Model\LabellistFactory $labellistFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_labellistFactory = $labellistFactory;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Actions');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Actions');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getReqest()
    {
        return $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    }
    
    public function getProductlabels()
    {
        $labelmodel = $this->_labellistFactory->create();
        return $labelmodel->getCollection();
    }
    public function getMediaUrl(){

        $media_dir = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
            ->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        return $media_dir;
    }
    public function getCurrentProductsku()
    {        
        $productdata = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
        return $productdata->getSku();
    }  
    public function getcheckval($labelid,$skuval){
        $serval = array();
        $flag = 0;
        $labelmodel = $this->_labellistFactory->create()->load($labelid);
        $labelarray = $labelmodel->getData();
        if (array_key_exists("cond_serialize",$labelarray)){
            $serval = json_decode($labelarray['cond_serialize'], true);
            if($serval != NULL){
                foreach($serval as $key=>$val){
                    if($key == 'conditions'){
                        //$data[] = $val; 
                        foreach($val as $nest){
                            if($nest['attribute'] == 'sku'){
                                if($nest['value'] == $skuval)
                                return $flag = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
        return $flag;
    }
    
}
```

Next in Productlabel.phtml

```
<div class="fieldset-wrapper-amasty-product-label" id="add-products-to-amasty-product-label">
    <fieldset class="fieldset-amasty-product-label" id="grop_fields-amasty-product-label">
        <legend class="legend-amasty-product-label">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Label')) ?></span>
        </legend>
        <br>
        <div class="store-scope-amasty-product-label">
            <div class="store-tree-amasty-product-label" id="add-products-to-amasty-product-label-content">
                <?php 
                    $skuval = $block->getCurrentProductsku();
                ?>
                
                 <?php foreach ($block->getProductlabels() as $_label):?>
                    <div class="label-name-amasty-product-label">
                        <?php
                                $checkcheked = $block->getcheckval($_label->getLabelId(),$skuval);                               
                               ?>
                        <input name="product[add_product_label_ids][]"
                               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_label->getLabelId()) ?>"
                               class="checkbox label-checkbox"
                               id="add_product_label_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_label->getLabelId()) ?>"
                               type="checkbox" 
                               <?php if ($checkcheked == 1):?>
                                    checked
                                <?php endif;?>
                               />
                        <img src="<?= $block->getMediaUrl().'amasty/amlabel/'.$_label->getProdImg() ?>" alt="<?= $_label->getName() ?>" >
                        <!--<label for="add_product_label_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_label->getLabelId()) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_label->getName()) ?>
                        </label>-->
                        
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

using i get checkbox list in product edit page but when click on save
under this observer "controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after" i am tring get print_r($POST)
all post are showing expect my custom filed.
can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it my own.
just add data-form-part="product_form" in input filed

```
<input name="add_product_label_ids[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_label->getLabelId()) ?>]"
                               data-form-part="product_form"
                               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_label->getLabelId()) ?>"
                               class="checkbox label-checkbox"
                               id="add_product_label_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_label->getLabelId()) ?>"
                               type="checkbox" 
                               <?php if ($checkcheked == 1):?>
                                    checked
                                <?php endif;?>
                                
                               />
```